Google Cloud Workflows fails with timeout error
Current setup/scenario: I have a google cloud workflow that triggers or runs a Cloud Run Job (not service). But the job runs for about an hour. So, the workflow, after 30 minutes, fails with a timeout error.
My questions:

In the workflow YAML, how can I just trigger the Cloud Run Job and exit immediately without waiting?
In the workflow YAML, how can I then keep on checking the status and sleep for a while until the triggered Cloud Run Job is complete (either successful or failed)?

Please help!

In the workflow YAML, how can I just trigger the Cloud Run Job and exit immediately without waiting? what do you mean by exit here? also check this article

As soon as the Cloud Run Job is triggered, the workflow should not wait until the completion. Once it returns back, then it can do the other step which is while true; do sleep 10m; exit when the job is finished; done.

the workflow, after 30 minutes, fails with timeout error. because The default timeout value is 1800 seconds (30 minutes) and can be changed to a maximum value of 31536000 seconds (one year) for long-running operations using the connector_params field. You can refer to this  document, it's in preview might have limited support but you can give a try

If you use the connector, you should ne have issue if you increase the timeout https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/googleapis/run/v1/namespaces.jobs/run

@Parthiban Nagarajan Have you checked the above comments, is that helpful?

I will add my answer below

I have added the following in the yaml
            connector_params:
                timeout: 5000
                polling_policy:
                    initial_delay: 900
                    multiplier: 1
                    max_delay: 900

This is as per the documentation available here.
https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/googleapis
I am not sure whether this feature was available when I raised the question.
Thanks everyone who tried to help me!
I am grateful to you.
